# Can't use LINQ's Expression Overload of MongoDB.Driver Include ProjectionDefinition

Tags: mongodb, linq, f#, .net-core

I'm having a hard time trying to Aggregations in a MongoDB database using F#. I've built this tiny sample code to illustrate:

```
open System
open MongoDB.Driver
open MongoDB.Bson

type MyDocument =
    { Id  : BsonObjectId
      Foo : string
      Bar : int
      Baz : bool
      Quz : DateTime }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ =
    let client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/faggregate")
    let db = client.GetDatabase("faggregate")
    let collection = db.GetCollection<MyDocument>("aggregations")

    let documents = collection.Aggregate().Group(Builders<MyDocument>.Projection.Include(fun x -> x.Foo))

    0
```

This stucks at:

```
No overloads match for method 'Include'. The available overloads are shown below.
member Include: 
   field: FieldDefinition<MyDocument> 
       -> ProjectionDefinition<MyDocument>
```

But `ProjectionDefinitionBuilder` have `public ProjectionDefinition<TSource> Include(Expression<Func<TSource, object>> field)`

Any one was able to use MongoDB Aggregations with F# already?

Comment: I haven't gotten to aggregation yet, but @nilekirk helped me figure out how to use projection here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64724797/977406

Answer (score 2):

`op_Implicit` is the key! Saw on MongoDB docs that `ProjectionDefinition`s could be created from plain-old Strings (JSON-ones), but on F# this `implicit` operator should be explicitly called using `op_Implicit`. So...

```
let group = ProjectionDefinition<MyDocument,_>.op_Implicit("""{ _id: "$Foo"}""")
let documents = collection.Aggregate().Group(group)
```

Working like a charm and I can write Aggregations just like in pure Mongo

Answer (score 0):

After reading Leo's answer, I studied the MongoDB documentation and there's a cleaner way that I felt very comfortable with to create a pipeline, using PipelineDefinition.Create(). This method accepts an `array<string>`, with the stages to be added, like in the example below, where I used Json syntax. Then it can be used in the Aggregate method:

```
let aggregation = PipelineDefinition.Create([|
        "{'$match': { 'communityEventId': '" + communityEventId + "'}}";
        """
            {
                '$lookup': {
                    'from': '_User',
                    'localField': 'email',
                    'foreignField': 'username',
                    'as': 'user'
                }
            }
        """;
        """
            {
                '$unwind': {
                    'path': '$user',
                    'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true
                }
            }
        """;
        """
            {
                '$addFields': {
                    'userId': '$user._id'
                }
            }
        """;
        """
            {
                '$project': {
                    'user': 0
                }
            }
        """
    |])

collection.Aggregate(aggregation).ToList()
```

In your case, you can just create a $match for Foo.

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/apidocs/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_PipelineDefinition_2.htm