# Projecting results from MongoDb Find in F#

Tags: .net, mongodb, f#, mongodb-query, mongodb.driver

I'm trying to query MongoDB using [MongoDB.Driver](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDB.Driver) and return a partial result using mongo projection.

I've figured out how to query without projection, but not a partial result.
This is my function for finding results:

```ml
let Find<'a> collectionName (filterDefinition: FilterDefinition<'a>) =
    let collection = database.GetCollection<'a> collectionName
    collection.Find(filterDefinition).ToEnumerable() |> List.ofSeq
```

This is an example of how I call it:

```ml
let findByIdFilter id =
    Builders<MyModel>.Filter.Eq((fun s -> s.id), id)

let results = Find collectionName (findByIdFilter id)
```

Let's say my model is something like that:

```ml
type MyInnerModel = {
    zInner: bool
}

type MyModel = {
    id: ObjectId
    x: int
    y: double
    z: MyInnerModel
}
```

And these are my projections:

```ml
type MyModelProjection1 = {
    id: ObjectId
    y: double
}

type MyModelProjection1 = {
    id: ObjectId
    x: int
    z: MyInnerModel
}
```

How do I construct my queries for following scenarios:

- Find documents matching `(fun (m: MyModel) -> m.z.zInner = false)` with projection to `MyModelProjection1`
- Find documents matching `(fun (m: MyModel) -> m.x = 5)` with projection to `MyModelProjection2`
- Find ALL documents with projection to `MyModelProjection1` or `MyModelProjection2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your projections like so:

```
let projection1 =
    Builders<MyModel>.Projection.Expression(fun model ->
        { id = model.id; y = model.y })

let projection2 =
    Builders<MyModel>.Projection.Expression(fun model ->
        { id = model.id; x = model.x; z = model.z })
```

You can then use them in the following way:

```
    let one =
        collection
            .Find(fun m -> m.z.zInner = false)
            .Project(projection1).ToEnumerable() |> List.ofSeq

    let two =
        collection
            .Find(fun m -> m.x = 5)
            .Project(projection2).ToEnumerable() |> List.ofSeq

    let three =
        collection
            .Find(fun _ -> true)
            .Project(projection1).ToEnumerable() |> List.ofSeq

    let four =
        collection
            .Find(fun _ -> true)
            .Project(projection1).ToEnumerable() |> List.ofSeq
```

Comment: Awesome! That definitely works!
Do you happen to know how to construct a similar definition for sorting the results?
`Builders<MyModel>.Sort` doesn't seem to have `.Expression`. It has `.Ascending(...)` (or `Descending(...)`), which takes `field: FieldDefinition<SessionSnapshot> -> SortDefinition<SessionSnapshot>`, but I have no idea how to construct these...

Comment: You can try e.g., `let sortDefintion = Builders<MyModel>.Sort.Descending(fun doc -> doc.x :> obj)`

Comment: Makes sence. I was hoping there'll be a better way without hiding the types. Thank you!